how to solve axiosError AggregateError when I download url image using axios?
I am trying to download image url. it's instgram image using axios and this code
 async downloadImage(url: string, fileName: string): Promise<string> {
    try {
      const response = await axios({
        headers: {
          'User-Agent':
            'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36',
        },
        maxRedirects: 20,
        timeout: 60000,
        url,
        method: 'GET',
        responseType: 'arraybuffer',
      })
      const buffer = await Buffer.from(response.data, 'binary')
      const path = `${this.rootPath}${fileName}`
      if (!(await drive.use().exists(path))) {
        await drive.use().put(path, buffer)
        logger.info(`Image downloaded ${path}`)
      } else {
        logger.info('already exists')
      }
      const fileUrl = await drive.use().getUrl(fileName)
      return fileUrl
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
      return error
    }
  }

and I make for loop for list of url images like that but some image can't download this function for doing so
  async downloadImageList(request: []) {
    const flatImageArray = this.getAllImage(request).flatMap((images) => images)
    const limit = pLimit(5) // Limit to 5 concurrent downloads

    const downloadPromises = flatImageArray.map((image) =>
      limit(async () => {
        const fileName = `${image.id}.jpg`
        try {
          await this.downloadImage(image.url, fileName)
        } catch (error) {
          logger.error(`Failed to download image ${image.id}: ${error}`)
        }
      })
    )

    await Promise.all(downloadPromises)
  }

but this image that I provided above I can't download it and this error message
AxiosError [AggregateError]
    at AxiosError.from (file:///home/mohamed/projects/zastoor-backend/node_modules/axios/lib/core/AxiosError.js:89:14)
    at RedirectableRequest.handleRequestError (file:///home/mohamed/projects/zastoor-backend/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:610:25)
    at RedirectableRequest.emit (node:events:530:35)
    at eventHandlers.<computed> (/home/mohamed/projects/zastoor-backend/node_modules/follow-redirects/index.js:38:24)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:518:28)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:500:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:518:28)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:169:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:128:3)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
    at Axios.request (file:///home/mohamed/projects/zastoor-backend/node_modules/axios/lib/core/Axios.js:45:41)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at ImageProcessing.downloadImage (/home/mohamed/projects/zastoor-backend/app/services/image_processing_service.ts:12:24)
    at AiController.generateContent (/home/mohamed/projects/zastoor-backend/app/controllers/ai_controller.ts:22:27)
    at SessionMiddleware.handle (/home/mohamed/projects/zastoor-backend/node_modules/@adonisjs/session/src/session_middleware.ts:81:22)
    at BodyParserMiddleware.handle (/home/mohamed/projects/zastoor-backend/node_modules/@adonisjs/bodyparser/src/bodyparser_middleware.ts:259:5) {
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  errors: [
    Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 186.235.41.33:443
        at createConnectionError (node:net:1646:14)
        at Timeout.internalConnectMultipleTimeout (node:net:1705:38)
        at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:575:11)
        at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7) {
      errno: -110,
      code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
      syscall: 'connect',
      address: '186.235.41.33',
      port: 443
    },
    Error: connect ENETUNREACH 2804:71d4:4000:2:face:b00c:3333:a3f:443 - Local (:::0)
        at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1180:16)
        at Timeout.internalConnectMultipleTimeout (node:net:1710:5)
        at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:575:11)
        at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7) {
      errno: -101,
      code: 'ENETUNREACH',
      syscall: 'connect',
      address: '2804:71d4:4000:2:face:b00c:3333:a3f',
      port: 443
    }
  ],
  config: {
    transitional: {
      silentJSONParsing: true,
      forcedJSONParsing: true,
      clarifyTimeoutError: false
    },
    adapter: [ 'xhr', 'http', 'fetch' ],
    transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
    transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
    timeout: 60000,
    xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
    xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
    maxContentLength: -1,
    maxBodyLength: -1,
    env: { FormData: [Function], Blob: [class Blob] },
    validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
    headers: Object [AxiosHeaders] {
      Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'Content-Type': undefined,
      'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36',
      'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, compress, deflate, br'
    },
    maxRedirects: 20,
    url: 'https://instagram.fqcj4-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.29350-15/455366979_1019262136112852_6745858522992926495_n.jpg?stp=dst-jpg_e15&_nc_ht=instagram.fqcj4-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=108&_nc_ohc=Y2o4dxr0ReIQ7kNvgHtz01w&edm=APs17CUBAAAA&ccb=7-5&oh=00_AYCim4181TTjjMWk397T1jdb9X6Kv9Pvf5rnuST9PG0-TA&oe=66CCF0DD&_nc_sid=10d13b',
    method: 'get',
    responseType: 'arraybuffer',
    data: undefined
  },
  request: <ref *1> Writable {
    _events: {
      close: undefined,
      error: [Function: handleRequestError],
      prefinish: undefined,
      finish: undefined,
      drain: undefined,
      response: [Function: handleResponse],
      socket: [Array],
      timeout: undefined,
      abort: undefined
    },
    _writableState: WritableState {
      highWaterMark: 16384,
      length: 0,
      corked: 0,
      onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
      writelen: 0,
      bufferedIndex: 0,
      pendingcb: 0,
      [Symbol(kState)]: 17580812,
      [Symbol(kBufferedValue)]: null
    },
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    _options: {
      maxRedirects: 20,
      maxBodyLength: Infinity,
      protocol: 'https:',
      path: '/v/t51.29350-15/455366979_1019262136112852_6745858522992926495_n.jpg?stp=dst-jpg_e15&_nc_ht=instagram.fqcj4-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=108&_nc_ohc=Y2o4dxr0ReIQ7kNvgHtz01w&edm=APs17CUBAAAA&ccb=7-5&oh=00_AYCim4181TTjjMWk397T1jdb9X6Kv9Pvf5rnuST9PG0-TA&oe=66CCF0DD&_nc_sid=10d13b',
      method: 'GET',
      headers: [Object: null prototype],
      agents: [Object],
      auth: undefined,
      family: undefined,
      beforeRedirect: [Function: dispatchBeforeRedirect],
      beforeRedirects: [Object],
      hostname: 'instagram.fqcj4-1.fna.fbcdn.net',
      port: '',
      agent: undefined,
      nativeProtocols: [Object],
      pathname: '/v/t51.29350-15/455366979_1019262136112852_6745858522992926495_n.jpg',
      search: '?stp=dst-jpg_e15&_nc_ht=instagram.fqcj4-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=108&_nc_ohc=Y2o4dxr0ReIQ7kNvgHtz01w&edm=APs17CUBAAAA&ccb=7-5&oh=00_AYCim4181TTjjMWk397T1jdb9X6Kv9Pvf5rnuST9PG0-TA&oe=66CCF0DD&_nc_sid=10d13b'
    },
    _ended: true,
    _ending: true,
    _redirectCount: 0,
    _redirects: [],
    _requestBodyLength: 0,
    _requestBodyBuffers: [],
    _eventsCount: 3,
    _onNativeResponse: [Function (anonymous)],
    _currentRequest: ClientRequest {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 7,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      outputData: [],
      outputSize: 0,
      writable: true,
      destroyed: false,
      _last: true,
      chunkedEncoding: false,
      shouldKeepAlive: true,
      maxRequestsOnConnectionReached: false,
      _defaultKeepAlive: true,
      useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
      sendDate: false,
      _removedConnection: false,
      _removedContLen: false,
      _removedTE: false,
      strictContentLength: false,
      _contentLength: 0,
      _hasBody: true,
      _trailer: '',
      finished: true,
      _headerSent: true,
      _closed: false,
      socket: [TLSSocket],
      _header: 'GET /v/t51.29350-15/455366979_1019262136112852_6745858522992926495_n.jpg?stp=dst-jpg_e15&_nc_ht=instagram.fqcj4-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=108&_nc_ohc=Y2o4dxr0ReIQ7kNvgHtz01w&edm=APs17CUBAAAA&ccb=7-5&oh=00_AYCim4181TTjjMWk397T1jdb9X6Kv9Pvf5rnuST9PG0-TA&oe=66CCF0DD&_nc_sid=10d13b HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
        'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
        'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36\r\n' +
        'Accept-Encoding: gzip, compress, deflate, br\r\n' +
        'Host: instagram.fqcj4-1.fna.fbcdn.net\r\n' +
        'Connection: keep-alive\r\n' +
        '\r\n',
      _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
      _onPendingData: [Function: nop],
      agent: [Agent],
      socketPath: undefined,
      method: 'GET',
      maxHeaderSize: undefined,
      insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
      joinDuplicateHeaders: undefined,
      path: '/v/t51.29350-15/455366979_1019262136112852_6745858522992926495_n.jpg?stp=dst-jpg_e15&_nc_ht=instagram.fqcj4-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=108&_nc_ohc=Y2o4dxr0ReIQ7kNvgHtz01w&edm=APs17CUBAAAA&ccb=7-5&oh=00_AYCim4181TTjjMWk397T1jdb9X6Kv9Pvf5rnuST9PG0-TA&oe=66CCF0DD&_nc_sid=10d13b',
      _ended: false,
      res: null,
      aborted: false,
      timeoutCb: [Function: emitRequestTimeout],
      upgradeOrConnect: false,
      parser: null,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      reusedSocket: false,
      host: 'instagram.fqcj4-1.fna.fbcdn.net',
      protocol: 'https:',
      _redirectable: [Circular *1],
      [Symbol(shapeMode)]: false,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
      [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype],
      [Symbol(errored)]: null,
      [Symbol(kHighWaterMark)]: 16384,
      [Symbol(kRejectNonStandardBodyWrites)]: false,
      [Symbol(kUniqueHeaders)]: null
    },
    _currentUrl: 'https://instagram.fqcj4-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.29350-15/455366979_1019262136112852_6745858522992926495_n.jpg?stp=dst-jpg_e15&_nc_ht=instagram.fqcj4-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=108&_nc_ohc=Y2o4dxr0ReIQ7kNvgHtz01w&edm=APs17CUBAAAA&ccb=7-5&oh=00_AYCim4181TTjjMWk397T1jdb9X6Kv9Pvf5rnuST9PG0-TA&oe=66CCF0DD&_nc_sid=10d13b',
    _timeout: null,
    [Symbol(shapeMode)]: true,
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
  },
  cause: AggregateError [ETIMEDOUT]: 
      at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1116:18)
      at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1184:5)
      at Timeout.internalConnectMultipleTimeout (node:net:1710:5)
      at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:575:11)
      at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7) {
    code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
    [errors]: [ [Error], [Error] ]
  }
}

I tried to retry connect for 3 times and all 3 times are fails. I tried to add custom user agent may connecting to this url has any restrictions in request or may rat-limit requests from specific IP addresses or user agents. I tried also to put timeout to axios may the network unstable or slow but still doesn't work and I used different value for timeout from 10000 to 60000. I tried also to add maxRedirects: 5 to avoide redirect chain in which The URL might go through multiple redirects before reaching the actual image, which can take time.
